# Help in drawing Proline Chemfig

Tags: chemfig, mol2chemfig

I have tried to do Proline with this attempt, however, I don't know how to consolidate this bond to CH_2 at the bottom.

```
\documentclass[grid,avery5371]{flashcards}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{letterpaper} 
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{landscape} 
\newcommand{\cardrows}{5} 
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{2} 
\setlength{\cardheight}{3in} 
\setlength{\cardwidth}{3.5in} 
\setlength{\topoffset}{0.50in} 
\setlength{\oddoffset}{0.75in} 
\setlength{\evenoffset}{0.75in}

\geometry{headheight=10pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\small MCAT FlashCards Chemistry}
\begin{document}
\begin{flashcard}[Amino Acids - NonPolarSideChains]
    {
        \chemfig{H_3N^+(-[6]H_2C(-[7]))-C(-[2]H)(-[6]CH_2(-[5]CH_2))-C(=[1]O)(-[7]O^{-})}
    }
Proline
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

[image: The image.]

Tried it this way, and it didn't work out that well.

```
\chemfig{CH_2(-[3]H_2C(-[2]H_2N^+(-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[0]C((=[1]O)(-[-1]O|{^-}))))(-[1]CH_2(-[-[2]]
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112626/134144

Comment: @leandriis  I was just looking at this one haha https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296217/chemfig-double-bond-gap-at-joint

Comment: @leandriis that one looks a bit different

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky is this ok for you?

`\chemfig[bond join=true]{H_2C(-[2,0.98,2,2,shorten >=-1pt]H_2N|{^+}\vphantom{C}?)-[-1](-[6,0.16,,,draw=none]CH_2)-[1]CH_2-[2]C?(-[2]H)(-[0]C(=[1]O)(-[-1]O|^{-}))}`

Comment: @polyn That works, just fine.

Comment: Possible related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112623/amino-acids-with-chemfig-some-bonds-are-falsely-positioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the bonds joining, you obtain

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H_2C(-[2,0.98,2,2,shorten >=-1pt]H_2N|{^+}\vphantom{C}?)
    -[-1,,,,shorten >=2pt](-[6,0.12,,,draw=none]CH_2)
    -[1,,,,shorten <=2pt]CH_2-[2]C?(-[2]H)(-[0]C(=[1]O)(-[-1]O|^{-}))}
\end{document}
```